# Get length of the textview and display the text accordingly

Tags: android, textview

In my application, I have a listview whose list item consists of a TextView and a Checkbox. The textview holds the name of some song and checkbox is always positioned at parent right with 5dip margin to all the sides.

Now the problem is, whenever the title of the song exceeds some limit, I want to show `"..."` after the songs title. e.g. Song's title is `"My heart will go on"`, I want to display only `"My heart wil..."`. And of course, if the title is short enough, no "..." needed. I don't want the text to be of marquee type. Can this be done? How?

Comment: Use android:elipsize="end" attribute of textview.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A textview provide attribute [ellipsize](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3aellipsize), simply add below attribute it will give same result as you want.

```
  android:ellipsize="end"
```

Comment: +1 for this answer.I also want to know how it will work for fixed length.Means as he said "My heart wil..." how it will put "..." after "My heart will" whould we use fixed length property ?

Comment: @RobinHood : Thanks. But my next problem is, if I want the textview not to occupy the whole width of the screen, do I need to fix the width of the textview. And if yes, then will it work on all the resolutions. Still trying it out. Thanks.

Comment: Then give fixed width to your textview.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the [Ellipsize](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3aellipsize) attribute/method on the TextView

Answer (score 2):

One more point to keep in mind, make sure you fix the size of your textview, or else the textview will continue to resize and the ellipsize will not come in effect. So either set the Layout_width or set the maxLines.